# How to block on a semaphore until its value is positive

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore

I want to use semaphores to make threads block until the semaphores become positive; but when my threads block on a semaphore, they unblock immediately on the first `sem_post` called on it, regardless of the value of that semaphore afterwards.

The situation is as follows:

1. Semaphore is set to `-1`.
2. A thread is started to wait `5` seconds before posting to the semaphore.
3. Once `5` seconds pass, the thread posts to the semaphore.
4. The semaphore's value is `0`, but the main process unblocks anyway.

Here is the code demonstrating the situation:

```
/**
 * testing whether sem_post on semaphore unblocks threads
 *     despite still being negative.
 **/
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

sem_t sem;

void *proc(void *arg)
{
    sleep(5);
    puts("posting");
    sem_post(&sem);
}

void setup()
{
    pthread_t pt;
    pthread_create(&pt, 0, proc, 0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    sem_init(&sem, 0, -1);

    setup();

    sem_wait(&sem);

    return 0;
}
```

I have found a crude way to overcome this issue by wrapping `sem_wait` in a busy loop that checks if the semaphore's value is `0`, but this seems like a wrong way to approach this.

Is there a more elegant way to block on a semaphore until its value is positive (not `0`, nor negative)?

Comment: The prototype for `sem_init`: `int sem_init(sem_t *sem, int pshared, unsigned int value);` Note the `unsigned`. Also, `man sem_overview:` *A  semaphore is an integer whose value is never allowed to fall below zero.[...]*.

Comment: @EOF so you are saying instead of setting it to negative, I set it to a really large number? O.o. I'm confused, if that's the case, there is no way to tell how many threads are waiting on the semaphore without creating a new semaphore for keeping track of that(which is tricky to do because then i'll be forced to sem_getvalue before any sem_wait call). Is that the normal behavior?

Comment: No, there is no way to tell how many processes are waiting for a semaphore from the `sem_t`. In fact, using a second semaphore to count the waiting processes would probably involve a race condition.

Comment: Everything I learnt in operating system course is a lie :( But thanks! I got a lot to think about.

Comment: Well, the semaphore is probably associated with some operating-system handle (like a `futex`), so the OS can schedule out a process that is blocked, and schedule it back in when the semaphore is posted. The OS will keep a list of processes blocked on the semaphore, but userspace doesn't usually see it.

Comment: @EOF so when implementing your own semaphores in kernel space, I would want to keep a track of all processes waiting on the semaphore(I will only notify one on each post though)?

Comment: How would you schedule them if you did not keep such a list?

Comment: @EOF that's a question that was bothering me for some time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't initialize the semaphore to `-1` because the API to initialize it only takes unsigned values.

> `int sem_init(sem_t *sem, int pshared, unsigned int value);`
>   <sub>[The Open Group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sem_init.html)</sub>

Probably, using `-1` caused a value larger than `SEM_VALUE_MAX` to be passed to `sem_init()`, and the initialization actually failed. You should check the return code, and if `errno` got set to `EINVAL`.

> The `sem_init()` function will fail if:
>
> [`EINVAL`]
>   The *value* argument exceeds `SEM_VALUE_MAX`.
>
> ...
>   <sub>[The Open Group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sem_init.html)</sub>

If you want threads to block on a semaphore on first call to `sem_wait`, initialize the semaphore to `0` instead.

If your system supports it, you can use `sem_getvalue` to find the number of waiters on the semaphore if the count is `0`.

> If *sem* is locked, then the value returned by `sem_getvalue()` is **either zero or a negative number whose absolute value represents the number of processes waiting for the semaphore** at some unspecified time during the call.
>   <sub>[The Open Group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sem_getvalue.html)</sub>

An implementation is allowed to choose which behavior they want, so this only works if your system supports it. Linux, for example, does not support it, since it chooses to return `0` if the semaphore count is `0`.

> If one or more processes or threads are blocked waiting to lock the
>          semaphore with `sem_wait(3)`, POSIX.1 permits two possibilities for the
>          value returned in `sval`: either `0` is returned; or a negative number
>          whose absolute value is the count of the number of processes and
>          threads currently blocked in `sem_wait(3)`.  **Linux adopts the former
>          behavior.**
>   <sub>[man7.org](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_getvalue.3.html)</sub>

Probably the most reliable way for you to implement what you want is to use a mutual exclusion variable, a condition variable, and a counter.

```
extern pthread_mutex_t lock;
extern pthread_cond_t queue;
extern atomic_uint waiters;

/* assume waiters is initially 0 */
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
++waiters;
while (my_status() == WAITING) {
    pthread_cond_wait(&queue, &lock);
}
--waiters;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try initializing the semaphore with zero or a positive integer value. If you initialize with zero `sem_init(&sem, 0, 0);` you will see the desired behavior.